# How can I change resolution of "my video" in Skype?

Tags: video, webcam, skype, resolution

I have a logitech Quickcam Pro 9000 connected to my ubuntu desktop and it works fine with Skype.

However, Skype inputs and sends my video at the native (for the webcam I think) resolution of 1600 x 1200. I can confirm that the camera supports a wide variety of resolutions starting from 160 x 120 upto 1600 x 1200 (including e.g., 320 x 240, 352 x 288) using cheese. I can select these resolutions and see the output is appropriately scaled.

Also, I don't see any improvements in smoothness of motion in the captured video so I suspect the original 1600 x 1200 is scaled down in the path somewhere.

Is it possible to somehow to enable this scaling capability towards Skype?

Answer (score 3):

There should be a skype configuration file in your home directory:

```
~/.Skype/YourUserName/config.xml
```

(Replace `YourUserName` with your skype user name). Open this file with a text editor, search for the `<Video>` tag and try to edit it match your preferred resolution:

```
<Video>
<CaptureHeight>240</CaptureHeight>
<CaptureWidth>320</CaptureWidth>
</Video>
```

Comment: IIRC I had tried this based on a post in forums or help.ubuntu.com, and this didn't work. However, I will try this again shortly.

Comment: There is no Video tag, so more information on the full path to the tag would be helpful. Using 2.2.0.35.